# Under what conditions will an extension messaging port close itself?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

A port will obviously close for any of the reasons mentioned [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#port-lifetime).

> - There are no listeners for runtime.onConnect at the other end.
> - The tab containing the port is unloaded (e.g. if the tab is navigated).
> - The frame from where connect was called has unloaded.
> - All frames that received the port (via runtime.onConnect) have unloaded.
> - runtime.Port.disconnect is called by the other end.

But I recently discovered that ports also close themselves when my laptop goes to sleep. Are there other scenarios in which persistent ports get closed?

Also, is there a good way to reestablish a connection? I'm thinking just calling chrome.runtime.connect() again.

Comment: firefox-addon is a completely different technology so I think you meant `firefox-webextensions`. As for the question, you'd need to delve into the browser source code to see the complete picture. Also, sometimes port-based messaging is an unnecessary complication. Why don't you use chrome.runtime.sendMessage()?

Comment: I've authored a [library](https://github.com/eejdoowad/mosi) that simplifies extension messaging. The [extension](https://github.com/lusakasa/saka-key) I'm building is on on the complicated side. I need persistent ports. Guess I'll look into the source code sooner or later.